# A type for JSON schema in a JSON schema?

Tags: json, jsonschema, json-schema-validator

I would like to have a schema, which describes a value, which is a JSON schema itself, for example

```
{
  "title": "Schema modification event",
  "description": "Describes and event of modification of another (arbitrary) JSON schema",
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "field_name": {
      "type": "string",
      "format": "json-pointer",
      "description": "Location where change occurred"
    },
    "field_schema": {
      "$ref": "https://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema",
      "description": "New schema of the location"
    }
  },
  "required": [
    "field_name",
    "field_schema"
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't a type for a schema, but what you've done with `field_schema` should work to ensure that `field_schema` is a JSON Schema.

You wouldn't be able to process `field_name` *using* the schema in `field_schema` within the same operation, though.  You'd have to do it in several steps:

1. Validate the payload (what the schema above should validate)
2. Extract your new data from wherever `field_name` is pointing and the schema at `field_schema`.
3. Validate the new data with the `field_schema` schema.