# Writing a JSON schema which includes properties of a JSON schema

Tags: jsonschema

I'm trying to define a JSON schema which validates an input which contains a JSON schema properties.

schema.json

```json
{
  "$schema": "https://json-schema.org/draft/2020-12/schema",
  "$id": "http://example.com/schema-validation",
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "someValue": {
      "type": "boolean"
    },
    "metaSchemaProperties": {
      "$ref": "https://json-schema.org/draft/2020-12/schema#/properties"
    }
  }
}
```

file.json

```json
{
  "someValue": true,
  "metaSchemaProperties": {
    "portRange": {
      "type": "string"
    }
  }
}
```

I also tried using the following values as `$ref`, without any success: https://json-schema.org/draft/2020-12/meta/core#/properties

However, the above schema fails to compile with the [`jv` CLI](https://github.com/santhosh-tekuri/jsonschema).

```
$ jv schema.json task.json

jsonschema file:///tmp/schema.json compilation failed
[I#/properties] [S#] doesn't validate with https://json-schema.org/draft/2020-12/schema#
  [I#/properties/$recursiveRef] [S#/properties/$recursiveRef/$ref] doesn't validate with 'https://json-schema.org/draft/2020-12/meta/core#/$defs/uriReferenceString'
    [I#/properties/$recursiveRef] [S#/$defs/uriReferenceString/type] expected string, but got object
  [I#/properties/definitions] [S#/properties/definitions]
    [I#/properties/definitions/$comment] [S#/properties/definitions/additionalProperties/$dynamicRef] doesn't validate with ''
      [I#/properties/definitions/$comment] [S#/type] expected object or boolean, but got string
    [I#/properties/definitions/type] [S#/properties/definitions/additionalProperties/$dynamicRef] doesn't validate with ''
      [I#/properties/definitions/type] [S#/type] expected object or boolean, but got string
  [I#/properties/dependencies] [S#/properties/dependencies]
    [I#/properties/dependencies/$comment] [S#/properties/dependencies/additionalProperties/anyOf] anyOf failed
      [I#/properties/dependencies/$comment] [S#/properties/dependencies/additionalProperties/anyOf/0/$dynamicRef] doesn't validate with ''
        [I#/properties/dependencies/$comment] [S#/type] expected object or boolean, but got string
      [I#/properties/dependencies/$comment] [S#/properties/dependencies/additionalProperties/anyOf/1/$ref] doesn't validate with 'https://json-schema.org/draft/2020-12/meta/validation#/$defs/stringArray'
        [I#/properties/dependencies/$comment] [S#/$defs/stringArray/type] expected array, but got string
    [I#/properties/dependencies/type] [S#/properties/dependencies/additionalProperties/anyOf] anyOf failed
      [I#/properties/dependencies/type] [S#/properties/dependencies/additionalProperties/anyOf/0/$dynamicRef] doesn't validate with ''
        [I#/properties/dependencies/type] [S#/type] expected object or boolean, but got string
      [I#/properties/dependencies/type] [S#/properties/dependencies/additionalProperties/anyOf/1/$ref] doesn't validate with 'https://json-schema.org/draft/2020-12/meta/validation#/$defs/stringArray'
        [I#/properties/dependencies/type] [S#/$defs/stringArray/type] expected array, but got string
  [I#/properties/$recursiveAnchor] [S#/properties/$recursiveAnchor/$ref] doesn't validate with 'https://json-schema.org/draft/2020-12/meta/core#/$defs/anchorString'
    [I#/properties/$recursiveAnchor] [S#/$defs/anchorString/type] expected string, but got object
```

Do you have an idea how to validate only properties?

Thanks!

Comment: May be related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75643991/a-type-for-json-schema-in-a-json-schema/75645184#75645184

Comment: @gregsdennis Yes the given question is related. However, the difference is that here I only want to accept schema's object properties instead of a complete schema.

Comment: Ah, I see.  JSON Schema doesn't have a way to extract an object's keys to use as a value somewhere else.  I think you'll need to follow Payam's advice and just write a custom schema for this need.

Answer (score 0):

The errors you're getting are because the value of `$ref` is required to point to a schema object, but you're pointing to an object whose values are schemas.  The validator you're using can't interpret (e.g.)

```
{
  "prop1": { "type": "string" },
  ...
}
```

as a schema, so it throws an error.